# vimでのdart環境のlspの設定方法

Tags: vim, dart

VimでのDart開発環境を構築しようとしているのですがうまく行きません。
`vim-lsp`と`vim-lsp-settings`をインストールしています。(dart-vim-pluginはインストールしていません。)
`vim-lsp-settings`のREADME.mdに記載されている例を参考に自分の環境に合うようにvimrcを変更しました。(下記)

しかし、この設定をしてdartのファイルを開き、`:LspStatus`をしても`analysis-server-dart-snapshot: exited`と表示されてしまいます。
どうすればよいのでしょうか?

```
let g:lsp_settings = {
    \ 'analysis-server-dart-snapshot': {
    \     'cmd': [
    \         '/home/username/.flutter/bin/dart',
    \         '/home/username/.flutter/bin/dart-sdk/cache/bin/snapshots/analysis_server.dart.snapshot',
    \         '--lsp'
    \     ],
    \ },
\ }
```

Comment: https://github.com/prabirshrestha/vim-lsp#debugging を参考に、
`let g:lsp_log_verbose = 1` と `let g:lsp_log_file = expand('~/vim-lsp.log')`
を設定して、ログを共有していただけないでしょうか

Comment: いろいろと試行したところ、うまくいった方法があったので回答として追記しました。

Answer (score 2):

DartのlspのREADME.mdを参考に、`lsp_settings`を下記のようにしたところ動作し、自己解決したので回答として記入しておきます。
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/pkg/analysis_server/tool/lsp_spec/README.md#running-the-server

```
let g:lsp_settings = {
    \ 'analysis-server-dart-snapshot': {
    \    'cmd': [
    \       '/home/username/.flutter/bin/dart',
    \       'language-server',
    \    ],
    \   'initialization_options': {
    \       'onlyAnalyzeProjectsWithOpenFiles': v:true,
    \   },
    \ },
\ }
```